# How can I make the X Windows bell use the default audio device?

Tags: linux, x-windows

The X window system provides the command

```
xset b on
```

to turn on the 'bell' that rings when Ctl-G is sent to an `xterm`, for example.  Unfortunately, the default seems to be to try to play the bell on the PC speaker, which I don't have on my hardware.

**How can I get X to play the bell on the default audio device**, like `/dev/dsp` or something of that nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pulseaudio has an option to do this:

```
pulseaudio --daemonize  # If you aren't already running it

pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/generic.wav bell-windowing-system
pactl load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system
```

This can be globally enabled in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Comment: @NormanRamsey: Since this worked, accept the answer with the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Mark: unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work reliably.  As far as I can tell, pulseaudio is a festival of pain.